# Make HTML/CSS responsive

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, responsive

Due to the skills of others in the community I have created this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbdoKV
HTML:

```css
.clipboard:after, .clip, .clip:before, .paper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.clipboard {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 27em;
  width: 23em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  border-radius: 3%;
  background: #b69b4c;
}
.clipboard:after {
  top: 2.25em;
  content: "";
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 20em;
  background: #fefefe;
}

.clip {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 4.2em;
  display: block;
  height: 10em;
  width: 17em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #A7A7A7;
}
.clip:before {
  content: "";
  top: -.5em;
  height: 5.3em;
  width: 5.3em;
  border: 2.2em solid #A7A7A7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.paper {
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  height: 23em;
  width: 20em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  background: #fefefe;
}
.paper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3.25em;
  width: 3.25em;
}
.paper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.25em;
  width: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<i class="clipboard">
    <i class="clip"></i>
    <i class="paper"></i>
</i>
```

As you can see this graphic does not scale / respond very well. If I set the width to 100%, everything loses its ratio / perspective. Ideally, I want to be able to set the clipboard width to 100% and everything (height, the clip at top, padding etc) will then scale correctly - much like an image would.

I can see 2 ways of making this responsive:

1. Changing the HTML/CSS - I have tried and failed
2. Converting this HTML/CSS to SVG - no idea where to start

How would you make this responsive?

Comment: So you want that your board fills the whole site? Like a frame ? And that it should adjust automatically at the screensize?

Comment: yes. if it was an image i would set the width to 100% and not set a height, and the image would scale and keep aspect ratio. if i do not set a height on this HTML, the clipboard does not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example as svg. There are a few sites where you can draw svgs.
Then you have the paths.
I think the different attributes are self explaining. If you have any questions ask please. I think the best is to read more about this if you want to use it.
Maybe [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp) but there are many more good sources.

```html
 <svg height="200" width="450">
 <path 
    id="lineAB" 
    fill="khaki"
    d="M9.778,96h108.445c5.400000000000006,0,9.778000000000006,-4.378,
       9.778000000000006,-9.778000000000006v-68.445c0,-5.4,-4.378,-9.778,
      -9.778000000000006,-9.778h-108.445c-5.4,0,-9.778,4.378,-9.778,
       9.778v68.445c0,5.400000000000006,4.378,9.778000000000006,
       9.778,9.778000000000006ZM8,16h112v72h-112v-72Z"
    transform="matrix(0.000503985 -1.04456 1.29502 0.000406514 -10.7973 124.73) 
    translate(-60,150)" />
 <path  
    fill="#C0C0C0" 
    d="M109.58289641986332,32.006086609509h8v-6.222000000000001c0,-5.3999999999999995,
      -4.378,-9.778,-9.778000000000006,-9.778h-30.221999999999994v-6.2219999999999995c0,
      -5.4,-4.378,-9.778,-9.778000000000006,-9.778h-20.445c-5.3999999999999995,0,
      -9.777999999999999,4.378,-9.777999999999999,9.778v6.222000000000001h-30.222c-5.3999999999999995,
       0,-9.778,4.378,-9.778,9.777999999999999v6.222000000000001h112ZM45.58289641986323,
       8.006086609509033h24v8h-24v-8Z" 
    transform="matrix(0.560377 0.00141111 -0.00141111 0.560377 25.8245 -9.95107)  
    translate(340,90)"/>
```

Now you only need to adjust the height and with 
respectively adding a scale at the transform attribute.

Comment: thanks for this. i did not use your svg but i managed to find one of the sites and i created a new svg.

Comment: My svg was only an example. Good that you managed it to insert your own!